# ¿Cómo transformar una lista a una cadena insertando saltos de linea? Python

Tags: python, string, lista

Tengo la lista

```
miLista = ["Estas", "son", "muchas", "palabras", ".", "Hola", "soy", "Luis", ".", "Hola"]
```

Y lo que deseo hacer es que al encontrar un punto se haga un **salto de linea** para que el resultado sea sólo una cadena con esta salida

```
Estas son muchas palabras.
Hola soy Luis.
Hola
```

Intenté con el método `join` pero no tuve éxito porque no consigo meter ese salto de linea cada que se encuentra con un punto.

El ***seudocódigo*** que he intentado es el siguiente:

```
for i in miLista:
    if i == ".":
       #separar la cadena con un salto de linea a partir del punto
    else:
       #separar la cadena con un espacio entre cada palabra
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) para agregar los saltos de línea:

```
>>> miLista = ["Estas", "son", "muchas", "palabras", ".", "Hola", "soy", "Luis", ".", "Hola"]
>>> p = ' '.join(miLista)
>>> p = p.replace(' . ', '.\n')
>>> print(p)
Estas son muchas palabras.
Hola soy Luis.
Hola
```

Podría decirse que ya está, pero si el último elemento fuese un punto `[... "Hola", "."]`, ese punto quedaría espaciado de la palabra `Hola`.

Para arreglarlo, simplemente agregar otro replace:

```
>>> p = p.replace(' .', '.')
```

Comment: La solución requiere que ningún elemento de la lista contenga el substring `" . "`. Prueba con `miLista = ["a", " . ", "b"]`

Answer (score 1):

La complicación del ejercicio es que:

1. Cada línea debe empezar con algo distinto de espacio.
2. Antes de un punto no debe haber un espacio.

Hacer un `join` a secas no funciona, pues insertaría un blanco entre la palabra y el punto que le sigue. También insertaria un espacio en la nueva línea:

```
Estas son muchas palabras .
 Hola soy Luis .
 Hola
```

Entonces, el método será juntar palabras hasta detectar un '.' y entonces aplicar un `join`, eliminando los espacios indeseados.

Luego de terminar el `for`, todavía pueden quedar palabras pendientes por escribir en `salida`.

```
miLista = ["Estas", "son", "muchas", "palabras", ".", "Hola", "soy", "Luis", ".", "Hola"]
salida = []
linea = ""
for palabra in miLista:
    if palabra == '.':
        linea += ' '.join(salida) + '.\n'
        salida = []
    else:
        salida.append(palabra)

if salida:
    linea += ' '.join(salida)
print(linea)
```

produce:

```
Estas son muchas palabras.
Hola soy Luis.
Hola
```